# Android - OutOfMemory while decoding Bitmap from resources on Android 5.0

Tags: android, bitmap, out-of-memory, transition, bitmapfactory

I have an ActivityA with a `RecyclerView`. Each item of the `RecyclerView` is composed of an `ImageView` and a `TextView`, as per the following XML:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:gravity="center_vertical"
          android:orientation="horizontal"
          android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
          android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
          android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
          android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:transitionName="@string/transition_image"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textSize="19sp"
        android:transitionName="@string/transition_text"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

And here is the adapter's `onBindViewHolder`, where the `onClick` event is set:

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final MainAdapter.ViewHolder holder, final int position){

    final MainActivity activity = (MainActivity) mainFragment.getActivity();

    final AdapterItem adapterItem = listOfItems.get(position);

    final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    options.inSampleSize = 4;
    options.inDither = false;

    final Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(activity.getApplicationContext().getResources(), adapterItem.getImageResource(), options);
    holder.imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

    holder.textView.setText(adapterItem.getText());

    holder.rootView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onClick(final View v){

            final Intent intent = new Intent(activity, ActivityB.class);

            final ActivityOptionsCompat activityOptionsCompat = ActivityOptionsCompat.makeSceneTransitionAnimation(activity, holder.imageView, v.getResources().getString(R.string.transition_image));
            final Bundle bundle = activityOptionsCompat.toBundle();

            intent.putExtra(ContentFragment.KEY_IMAGE, adapterItem.getImageResource());
            intent.putExtra(ContentFragment.KEY_TEXT, adapterItem.getText());

            ActivityCompat.startActivity(activity, intent, bundle);

        }
    });
}
```

As you can see, when a click is performed in one of the items, I start ActivityB. Here is the code of ActivityB:

```
public class ActivityB extends AppCompatActivity{

@Override
protected void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState){

    supportRequestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_ACTIVITY_TRANSITIONS);

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_b);

    final Bundle args = getIntent().getExtras();
    if(args != null){

        final ImageView imageViewBig = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageViewBig);

        final int imageResource = args.getInt(ContentFragment.KEY_IMAGE);

        final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        options.inSampleSize = 2;
        options.inScaled = true;
        options.inDither = false;

        final Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), imageResource, options);
        imageViewBig.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

        Palette.from(bitmap).generate(new Palette.PaletteAsyncListener(){

            @Override
            public void onGenerated(final Palette palette){

                final Palette.Swatch profileSwatchDark = UtilPalette.getProfileSwatchDark(palette);
                if(profileSwatchDark != null){

                    final int vibrantRGB = profileSwatchDark.getRgb();

                    Utils.tintSystemBars(getWindow(), vibrantRGB);
                }
            }
        });
    }

}
```

As you can see, a transition animation is played having the `ImageView` as a shared element:

[image: ActivityA with RecyclerView items]

[image: Activity transition animation]

[image: ActivityB]

Everything works fine. My problem is if I tap on an item from the `RecyclerView` (ie, go to ActivityB), go back, then type on an item again, go back, etc, and repeat this a few times (about 10), the app crashes with an OutOfMemory Exception on ActivityB's `BitmapFactory.decodeResource` method.

I am running the code above on Android 5.0, so my understanding is that the Bitmap memory of the previous allocations should be automatically cleaned (as per the change on Honeycomb in which the pixel data of the Bitmap is now stored in the VM memory and not in native memory, therefore being eligible for garbage collection). But it seems this is not the case here. The app keeps crashing after a few transitions from ActivityA to ActivityB.

Furthermore, I can see on the new memory profiler screen on Android Studio that the memory keeps going up each time I enter ActivityB (which is expected as the big image is being loaded from the resources), **but it never goes down when I press the back button** (ie, when ActivityB is finished), resulting in a crash when it reaches the top (the 96MB limit):

[image]

Comment: Have you tried to explicitly `null` the image drawable (e.g. in `onDestroy()`)? If that helps, you can also explicitly recycle the Bitmap, which makes any cached value unusable. This also often gives you the location of the actual problem ...

Comment: You should post more code. It seems very likely that you are leaking ActivityB somewhere so this is not garbage collected.

Comment: @dhke I have explicitly set the image drawable to null in onDestroy (like you said) and it seems to have done the trick! Now the memory consumption goes down when I close ActivityB. Now the question is: why? Why do we need to do this manually? Shouldn't the garbage collector take care of it automatically?

Comment: @Tiago From what I gather from [the code](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/widget/ImageView.java#L809), the only reference to the bitmap is held by the `ImageView`, but that too *should* be garbage collected after the activity is destroyed ...

Comment: Indeed, same issue here. Removing activity transitions makes the memory usage back to normal.